# Prolog predicate that extracts all words immediately following a word in a given list of words

Tags: prolog

As it says in the title, i need to get all the words after a specifc word in prolog, for example:

```
?- find([in, house, car, in, shop, no, more, apples, in, table], in , X).

X = [house, shop, table] ;

No
```

This is the code i've written so far:

```
find([H,H_1|_],H,[H_1]).
find([Head,Head_1|Tail], Term, [Head|Result]) :-
     find(Tail, Term, Result).
```

After i run it, i get:

```
X = [house] ;

X = [in, car, shop, more, table] ;

No
```

Comment: Say `in` occurs twice, do you want *two* answers, or one?

Comment: Well, I only need one answer, i mean, if you could point out, where i'm doing wrong in the code, and also, what do you mean by "say in occurs twice"?

Comment: I meant Prolog giving two answers. Say you have `find([a,b,c,a,d],a,X)`. Do you want it to unify `X` *only* with `X = [b,c,a,d]`. Or should `X = [d]` be returned as well?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I want for Prolog to give only one answer, but, in your example, that answer should be:
    X = [b,c,d].

Comment: sorry I misread your question. It's clear now what you mean.

Comment: another question: what if there is no immediate next element. What should be the result of `find([a,b,c],c,X)`?

Comment: Then it would simply have to return No

Comment: well there are still two open questions: what to do if the match is the last element (so what should `X` be for `find([a,b,c],c,X)`) and what if the match occurs two consecutive times (like `find([a,a,b],a,X)`)? I know it is sometimes annoying but edge- and corner cases are important.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is, this is an assignment, and in it, it doesn't specify about these corner cases, only what i've written in the description, so, let's say for the second question, it should return: b and for the first question, it should return No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is probably located here:

```
find([H,H_1|_],H,[H_1]).
```

This code unifies the list with the **first** element after the match. You then unify the third parameter (which is here used as a "result") with a list containing the single occurrence.

Note furthermore that it is also possible that we reached the end of the list. So in that case the predicate will fail as well.

Basically there are four cases here:

- we reach the end of the list, the "result" parameter should unify with the empty list;
- we found the element and there is a next element (that is also a match), we perform one step and continue our search;
- we found the element and there is a next element (that is *not* a match), we add that element and continue our search;
- the head does not match, we continue our search.

We can implement these possibilities as:

```
find([],_,[]).            % we reach the end of the list


find([H,H|T],H,T2) :-     % there is a match, the successor is also a match
    find([H|T],H,T2).     % perform one hop

find([H,N|T],H,[N|T2]) :- % there is a match, add the next element
    N \= H,
    find(T,H,T2).         % and continue

find([N|T],H,T2) :-       % there is no match
    N \= H,
    find(T,H,T2).         % we continue
```

This produces:

```
?- find([in, house, car, in, shop, no, more, apples, in, table], in , X).
X = [house, shop, table] ;
false.

?- find([a,b,c],c,X).
false.

?- find([a,b,c,a,d],a,X).
X = [b, d] ;
false.

?- find([a,a,b],a,X).
X = [b] ;
false.
```

(`Yes`/`No` are in [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) `true/false`).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing better than writing simple programs to learn a language. After you grasp the basics, you could be interested into more *idiomatic* approach:

```
find(L,W,Fs) :- findall(F, append(_,[W,F|_],L), Fs).
```

Comment: Thanks for a different approach to the problem.